# How to do code-review changes before submitting in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to get code-reviews done by PEER before submitting the changes in Perforce?I heard `p4 shelve` is an option,is it right?is there a better way?

```
p4 [g-opts] shelve [files ...]
```

Answer (score 4):

I would say that "p4 shelve" is the best way to do code review.  You might want to look at Swarm, which offers code review features that are based around shelving.

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_shelve.html
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.1/manuals/swarm/chapter.code_reviews.html

Comment: whats the exact `p4 shelve` command to shelve a change,i see lot of options,confused as to which one to use

Comment: To shelve the files open in the default change, just run "p4 shelve".  if you have other things going on, use other options.  Can't tell you what options to use without knowing what other circumstances you have going on.

Comment: ok,I have shelved a change `896784 `,how do I have it reviewied by my peer and submit the shelved changes after review?

Comment: Tell the peer to "p4 unshelve -s 896784", or use Swarm as suggested earlier to visually review/comment, or (etc)

Comment: If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Not only for the question, but for any other questions that you would ask in future.